# Is there a way for Google Cloud Python Authentication via the JSON keyfile itself and not the file path?

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables

So for Ruby, you can set the JSON content into the environmental variable of `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON`. I am trying to find the documentation for Python, but all I can see is documentation loading the authentication for file path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way to do it, but I want to know if there is a better way. Using the `google-auth` library, I can do something like this:

```
import json

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

"""
Securely get content of JSON file from protected memory because having
the credential file plainly on the filesystem is unsafe
"""

service_account_info = json.loads(json_file_content_string)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)
client = bigquery.Client(project='secret-proj', credentials=credentials)
```

More about the library here: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the environment variables on Python using the following:

```
import os
print os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON']
```

Comment: So with `google-cloud-ruby`, according to https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/AUTHENTICATION.md, I know that Datastore can autoreads `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON` as the content of the json file, but with `google-cloud-python`, according to https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/core/auth.html, I can only supply the path to the json, and for security reasons, I don't want the file on non-volatile memory. So Python can read environment variables, but it does not help me authenticate.

Comment: Even when on `google-cloud-ruby` Datastore autoreads `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON` you would need to put the JSON path on the environment variable with `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/keyfile.json"`.


It will work exactly the same with Python the only difference is that it doesn't read it automatically.

Comment: Let me clarify: `google-cloud-ruby` does not require a path to the `keyfile.json` at all. `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON` only ever needs the contents of the json. If I want to feed it the path, in ruby, I would use `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE` instead. Also `google-cloud-python` does not use `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON`.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, you need to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with a path to the JSON file instead.

See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more details.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't gain anything from your answer. I already read those docs, but Google definitely need to update them since those docs do not include the ruby-exclusive answer of `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON`. So I cannot trust them generally.