# google-cloud-storage get_bucket very slow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the python google-cloud-storage library.  I have code as follows:

```
with open("config/google_auth.json") as f:
    credential_info = json.load(f)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credential_info)
client = storage.Client(project=credential_info["project_id"], credentials=credentials)
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
```

When I run this code locally, `get_bucket` takes a long time to resolve.  It took 105 seconds, before finishing, but did complete successfully.

Weirder yet, adding a timeout argument changes the behavior.  The following call to `get bucket` runs in 5 seconds, completing successfully:

```
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME, timeout=1)
```

Setting `timeout=5` causes it to take 25 seconds.

Setting `timeout=0.1` causes it to take less than a second.

I'm on the latest version of the library (1.33.0 as of time of posting) with Python 3.6.2

Why is `get_bucket` so slow?  Why does passing a timeout argument make it run faster?  And why, when I pass the timeout argument, does the call return successfully despite taking substantially longer than the timeout?

Comment: That's interesting since the `https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/client.html#Client.get_bucket` dictates that the default timeout is 60 seconds, but your operation took 105. And even though you set it to 1 second, it took 5 seconds without timing out. What is your python version? What happens if you set the timeout to be higher? Have you tried loading in the JSON directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394413/is-there-a-way-for-google-cloud-python-authentication-via-the-json-keyfile-itsel

Comment: I added some details to the question.  The runtime seems to be at least somewhat linearly related to the value I pass for timeout.

Comment: It could also be passed in as a tuple. Have you tried experimenting with that?

Comment: If you try running `gsutil perfdiag gs://your-bucket` it will output many measurements. Do the Metadata operation trials have latency as high as you're seeing? If not, the problem is likely something in your client/library. But if the perfdiag Metadata measurements are also slow look at the other measurements to try to see if it might be a local problem (like utilized CPU or RAM), a network problem (retransmitted segments), or something about your cloud configuration (e.g., trying to access a bucket in a different continent).

Comment: I had the same issue and also the same apparent behaviour (setting an explicit timeout weirdly seemed to make thins work faster). For me it turned out to be an active VPN connection that seemed to compromise the communication with GCS.